# no crontab for [username] - using an empty one

Tags: cron

I want to run a bash file (`abc.sh`) on the desktop that runs a python file on the desktop as well. How can I do that?

I tried to do the following simple task just to test the crontab: (here the `abc.sh` script is supposed to make a folder on the desktop):

---

What I did on Terminal:

```
crontab -e
```

Added the following below all the comment when crontab opened in the terminal itself.

```
* * * * * abc.sh
```

Code inside `abc.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ebrisk/Desktop
mkdir "testcrontab"
```

---

I understand that it might have to do something with the PATH environment variables but that's about it. I don't understand their answers.

Comment: list down the entry you make in crontab

Answer (score 3):

first

`sudo crontab -e`

Under the line

```
m h  dom mon dow   command
```

Enter

```
* * * * * sh /path-to-your-script/abc.sh
```

Be sure to make the scipt with execute permission

```
chmod +x abc.sh
```

Comment: Here is what I did:
**On the Terminal**
'chmod +x /path/to/scripts/abc.sh'

**then**

sudo crontab -e

**Under the line**

**m h  dom mon dow   command**

**I Entered**

* * * * * sh /path-to-your-script/abc.sh

___
No folder was created on the desktop

Comment: you have to state at which minute and hour you want to run so you have to put for example 10 8 * * * sh /path-to-your-script/abc.sh

Comment: with * * * * * should it not do that every minute? I did put in the time any ways but still, no folder was created on the desktop.

Comment: make an echo in your script just to check

Comment: Here is the new code in **abc.sh**
`#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ebrisk/Desktop/
mkdir "testcrontab"
echo "blahblahblah"` ___ and nothing happened

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I figured out while I selected an editor to create my cron jobs, I always used to rename the files with a suitable name I could identify. This time around I kept the name as suggested by system and did not rename the file. This is first time I was using crontab on my system. And it worked. I saw o/p on terminal saying installing crontab. So for the first time I think you have to go with the suggested name.